# Does xamarin form maps component conflicts with carouselpage?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page which contains a xamarin.form.map component. Then, by pressing a button, the next page is a carousel page.
However, when i launch the app on an Android device, the carouselpage content is empty !!

If you comment the map component, carouselpage works well... am i missing something ?

If you want to test, i have uploaded the project on the xamarin's forum, [here the link](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/pl/08mizsims6m6.zip)

Don't forget to insert your Google Maps Android API key, i've removed mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your Carousel before pushing. 
Like: Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new YourCarouselPage()));

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, I got an exception : Java.Lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup